# transaction manager is not rollback the transaction when exception triggered in committing the second transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactionmanager

I am using two DB in my application named DB1, DB2. for managing the transaction using the org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="DB1" />
            <ref bean="DB2" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

DB1, DB2 is the reference of "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" class.
In my code, I am updating both DB in my service class. As i know hibernate committed the transaction in reverse order so DB2 got committed successfully but when hibernate is going to commit DB1 then getting this exception

```
SQL Error: 12899, SQLState: 72000 
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"."COLUMN_1" (actual: 13, maximum: 12)
```

so DB1 gets rollback but DB2 is not getting rollback.

I want- When there is an error in DB1 then DB2 also get rollback.

Comment: You cannot. As the other transaction is already committed, you cannot rollback an already committed transaction. Either compensate for it, or use JTA if you need multiple transactional resources.

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum, I am using Hibernate and at this moment can not move to JTA. Hibernate is the widely used framework and has the chained transaction manager to manage multiple transactions resource. There should be a way to manage the situation otherwise it is an issue in the ORM.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ORM but with how transactions work. A committed transaction cannot be rolled back. You have 2 individual transactions.